# Point cmake to a specific library instead of vcpkg

Tags: windows, cmake

I am trying to build a package developed for Linux to build on Windows. I am new to CMake. It requires protobuf 22, which I installed in `C:/protoc-22.0-win64`. However, it is picking the protobuf version from vcpkg, which came with it after installing arrow. How do I make the cmake point to the right version? I need to fix this issue for multiple other libraries, so some generic guidance/examples would help. Thank you.